# Mysqli fetch array not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am in the process of making my mysql querys prepared in an attempt to increase security, however I have a problem when I attempt to fetch the results of a prepared statement. I have researched for the cause of the error, however many of the examples use complex code and I do not know how to apply the solution to my code.

**The error**

mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

**My code**

```
$query = "SELECT cid, user1, user2 FROM convotable 
WHERE user1 = ? OR user2 = ? ORDER BY createtime ASC";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
if ($stmt) {
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $user1, $user2);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ 
$cid = $row['cid'];    
$user1 = $row['user1'];  
$user2 = $row['user2'];  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and set variable that you bind in **mysqli_stmt_bind_param()**

```
 $query = "SELECT cid, user1, user2 FROM convotable 
 WHERE user1 = ? OR user2 = ? ORDER BY createtime ASC";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
 if ($stmt) 
 {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $user1, $user2);
   $user1=1; //set variable
   $user2=2; //set variable
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
   { 
     $cid = $row['cid'];    
     $user1 = $row['user1'];  
     $user2 = $row['user2'];  
   }
 }
```

See for more :http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: that is because, Your query is failing and returning a false value

Comment: The error I get is: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given. I know that the query it self is correct as I have used it before, I believe that the error is within the way that the array is being assigned to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be what you need, but I find using PDO (alternative to mysqli) alot more easy and clear:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$user1 = '123';
$user2 = '234';

$query = "SELECT cid, user1, user2 FROM convotable
         WHERE user1 = ? OR user2 = ? ORDER BY createtime ASC";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $user1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $user2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo 'something went wrong';
    die;
}

print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```